# $C^1$ versus smooth submanifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Is the graph of $f(x)=|x|\,x$ (or any $C^1$ function that is not $C^\infty)$ a *smooth* embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with its standard differential structure?

I apologize if this is too elementary, but I got somehow confused. I understand that the question is equivalent to the existence of a diffeomorphism of a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ that takes the graph of $f$ to a straight line.

Comment: And by smooth you mean $C^{\infty}$. No, and it's a good exercise.

Comment: The question was implicitely answered negatively as a reply to a similar question of mine [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116940/gluing-submanifolds-along-their-common-boundary/1117485#1117485), so I vote to close this.

Comment: Here is a hint: a $C^{k}$ submanifold is a graph of a $C^{k}$ function in almost all linear coordinate systems. You get $\alpha x + f(x)$ $C^{\infty}$ for almost all $\alpha$ ...

Comment: It's your own question, and there are no answers. If you want to delete it, you can do so on your own (that is, you don't need mods to do it for you)